# Querying location data - is it possible to set an entities "discoverable radius" with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and I'm making a chat app prototype, so I'm using Realtime Database for it.

I know that by adding GeoFire to Realtime Database can do something similar to the following with my users and their posts;

[image: User looking for posts]

This is where a user can "discover" nearby posts by virtue of them being within a certain radius of his geohash and querying it with GeoFire.

I'm clueless as to how I should go about the following though;

[image: Posts looking for users]

In this example, the posts have their own discovery radius - and the users walking around are able to "discover" the posts. Maybe some have a bigger radius than others based on some condition.

How do you go about doing this in Firebase?